# Create New Database from MVC application

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

My application offers Registration option and once the registration is approved i have to create a seperate Database for the newly created user

For every User we have a set of excercises to map  and the structre is like

```
Level [ Id Name ] -  Total 5 levels 
Questions [Id LevelId Question] - 5 Questions in every Level
UserQuestionsMap [Id userId QuestionId] - 25 questions will be mapped for every user
```

I want to create a new database for every user on the registration approval process with the master tables 
Level , Questions and UserQuestionsMap

How can i do this? User1Db , User2Db ,......, Db etc with the master tables and values on it

I am using EntityFramework models for Registartion and approval process
So is there any easy way of automating the process of db creation

Comment: A new database for every user? Can you explain why do you need a distinct database per user?

Comment: New Db for every user , since i am planning to give different Db for every users  instead of mixing datas of all users together [we have to give backup of db file to every users also , so if keep in a single Db it is easier]

Comment: I don't know... I cannot see why mixing the data as you say is a problem. You can model your Users as an Entity in your relational model and filter your data accordingly. Take under consideration that in sql server you can have up to 32767 databases per instance. And finally the sql server backup contains all the objects of the database not only the data but also indexes, stored procedures etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for creating new DB in your case, but you can always separate data on logical levels.

Means, you can introduce 'comapany'/'user' table where data will be different for each company/user depends on their unique id.

Why to create multiple databases and add to the cost.